# Raspberry Pi Auto Mounting to the Wrong Location

Tags: raspbian-jessie, mount, ntfs

I rebooted my Raspberry Pi and discovered it has auto mounted the external hard drive under `/media/pi/driveLabel`! I had originally created a mount point at  `~/USBHDD/` before the reboot.

How can I unmount from `/media/pi` and auto mount on  `~/USBHDD/` every time I boot my Raspberry Pi? I'm running Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tell your system that you want this drive mounted to the directory of your choice by modifying `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1 /home/pi/USBHDD/ auto,users,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

Or, if you want only a particular drive to be mounted there and happen to know its UUID:

```
UUID=XXXX /home/pi/USBHDD/ auto,users,rw,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0
```

[Here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-mount-a-usb-flash-disk-on-the-raspberry-pi/) is a good tutorial on the subject in case you get lost or face issues.

Comment: `/dev/sda` is generally a block device node, and what you mount are *partitions containing filesystems*, e.g., `/dev/sda1` -- although this then presumes the  first partition (so the UUID option is probably better).

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for a quick catch, that's exactly what I meant to write.

Comment: I think using `UUID` would be better approach, however how do I know `UUID` ? maybe `sudo blkid`

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz For starters try `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev does /etc/fstb executes before /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz yes, it does.