# Raspberry pi boots to root user in terminal when mounted USB HDD is not plugged in

Tags: raspbian, usb, hard-drive

This is a weird problem, I have raspibian OS Jessie installed on my pi3 . So the problem is Raspberry pi boots to root user in terminal when mounted USB HDD is not plugged into USB port.

I have set up manual mount from /etc/fstab ( follow this link how and why I mount up manually 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53622/49991)

To me it feels like it's a bug that if external USB drive is not mounted it falls back to root user in terminal mode. Well that shouldn't happen at all.

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that

# New NTFS HD: Archives&Backup on Sat Aug 20-  13:00:00 IST 2016
# UUID=120063E80063D171 /home/pi/USBHDD/ ntfs rw,auto,users,uid=pi,gid=pi 0 0  /dev/sda1 /home/pi/USBHDD/ auto,users,rw$
```

the last line above is where I have commented both ways to mount the disk, Earlier I was using UUID method but later I decided to use the one that starts with `/dev/sda1` but since HDD is not with me I had to disable it.

Comment: You have provided almost no information (like your original). If you can't even be bothered to list your `/etc/fstab` don't expect any help. PS Raspbian does NOT have a root user enabled by default so you need to clarify what else you have done.

Comment: what else do I need to mention I have added `/etc/fstab/` .

Comment: There's something else going on here.  It's impossible for me to say what though without examining the system.  You could have a look through  `/var/log/syslog` post boot to see if there are any clues but unless they are glaringly obvious I'm not sure how much help that will be to you.  Is the root filesystem in read-write or read-only mode when it does this (try and create a file somewhere to check)?

Comment: syslog is huge, can you tell me what should I grep some specifics that can be helpful